# Group Results By Month and Column

Tags: postgresql

Is there anyway i can group the results by month and by type? With the query below i managed to group by month but the "type" is not grouping.

query:

```
select date_trunc('month',processingdate),type,sum(itemcount), sum(itemamount)
from test
where  date_trunc('month',processingdate) >= now() - interval '1 month'
group by type,date_trunc('month',processingdate)
order by processingdate
```

Data in table:

```
date_trunc    type      sum      sum
1/1/20         11        5        1
1/2/20         12        3        2
1/3/20         11        2        3 
1/4/20         12        3        5
```

Expected Results:

```
date_trunc    type      sum      sum
1/1/2020       11        7        4
1/1/2020       12        6        7
```

Comment: you have two date (1/1/20, 1/3/20) for type = 11, which one to use and why?

Comment: @User9123 I want to group all 11 and all 12 for the month into one. So i can get the total months SUM of 11 and 12's.

Comment: @Ben21.  The "Data in table" looks like the output from the query, but not the actual data in table.  Would be nice to see some raw data (ordered by date).   If this is incorrect, what results are you getting from query?  What date format are you working with (dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy)?  That's why ordering by date is useful or just do select now()

Comment: + you cant "order by processingdate" in group by expression, try "order by 1" or "order by date_trunc('month',processingdate)"

Comment: @User9123 that worked! thank you!